# Keep children when parent is deleted

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, cascade

I'm currently facing the following problem: I have a relationship between `countries` and `cities`. As you might imagine, this relationship is fairly simple, a `country` can have multiple `cities` whereas the `city` only belongs to one `country`. Once I delete a `country` I want to keep the belonging `cities` existing in my database.

My domain model looks as following:

Class **Country**:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "COUNTRIES" )
public class Country extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private Set< City > cities = new HashSet<>();

    @Column( name = "NAME", length = 80, nullable = false, unique = true )
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    public Set< City > getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities( Set< City > cities ) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
}
```

Class **City**:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "CITIES" )
public class City extends BaseEntity {

    private String  name;
    private Country country;

    @Column( name = "NAME", length = 120, nullable = false )
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name = "COUNTRY_ID", nullable = true )
    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry( Country country ) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Just for your information, `BaseEntity` simply keeps the Primary Key as well as information when the entity was created or modified.

How can I achieve that my cities are not deleted when a country is removed from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace  `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

with

```
cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH }
```

in

```
 @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    public Set< City > getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
```

Comment: Well, I tried that and it looked promising, but once I delete a Country, I receive a DataIntegrityViolationException because the foreign key has no corresponding entry. So I guess I need to tell Hibernate to set the `CITY.COUNTRY_ID` to null or -1? (FYI: the `@JoinColumn` attribute in `City` has `nullable = true`).

Comment: @mhp That's likely due to your City still holding a reference to your country. You need to unset that first.

Comment: @mabi Okay, I wasn't sure if Hibernate does that for me or not. Seems it does not. Thanks!